# Is it possible to open several web pages when browser is started?

Tags: browser, automation, browser-tabs

I am searching for browser option or plugin (it will be best if it is available in Web Kit browsers,Opera or Firefox - not IE) that allows me to open several web pages when it is initially started.

For example, let's say that I have some file with settings in which I have pointed the following websites:

1. Google +
2. gmail
3. StackOverflow.com
4. SuperUser.com
5. dba.stackexchange.com
6. linkedin
   etc...

and when I firstly started the Chrome browser, all this sites will be opened in new tabs and because the browser has saved my passwords I will be logged in.

I will find this very helpful because:

1. It will saves me time
2. I will not miss anything when I turn on my computer (for example to forget to check my mail)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using Google Chrome:

```
Settings > On startup > Open a specific set of pages
```

Add whatever pages to the list that you wanted opened.

Alternatively, I never close my browser, so I just use "`Continue where I left off`" to recover from crashes and updates.

Comment: … except that Chrome occasionally forgets which pages it had open after restarting. Infuriating. Data loss (which this is!) is simply an unacceptable bug category. Ah well …

Comment: @KonradRudolph In the same vein, I've been in the middle of typing posts on forums and [SU], had chrome crash, and usually recover text I had typed less than 3 seconds before it crashed. I'll take this feature over it always remembering the exact pages any day. ;) In any case, Chrome's track record for crashing at all has been miles better than Firefox's when I last used it (admittedly, a long time ago). Firefox just doesn't handle 80-100 tabs well.

Comment: @KonradRudolph and Darth: Chrome probably does crash recovery similar to Firefox - every _foo_ minutes, it saves the state of the browser, and recovers from that.  If you're lucky, it just saved.  If not, it was just short of saving again.  (In Firefox, _foo_ can be changed in `about:config`)

Comment: @DarthAndroid - anecdotally, Firefox does far better now, in my experience, than Chrome does. CHrome w/26 tabs right now is using over 1 GB ram. Firefox with 367 tabs open (not all loaded, per my settings) is using ~400 MB of RAM. My workflow simply wouldn't work in Chrome (not that I expect it should)

Answer (score 22):

In Firefox, with the pages open select Options from the Tools menu, on the General tab.
Select Show My Home Page from the 'When Firefox Starts', then click on 'Use Current Pages'

Comment: Additional note, Firefox has the same "Show my windows and tabs from last time" as Chrome, as was mentioned in @DarthAndroid's answer

Comment: @Izkara but will this show all your tabs that had been loaded by the browser?If yes, it does not help, because it could re-load the wanted sites with addition of many other unnecessary.

Answer (score 18):

A solution to this that is fairly cross-browser is creating a shortcut containing all the desired webpages:

```
<browser-executable> [webpage1] [webpage2] [webpage3] ...
```

The neat thing about this solution is that you can even use the link if the browser is already open. It will simply create new tabs.

Answer (score 17):

If I understand what you're asking for, Firefox has had this built in for several years now:

[image: Firefox]

You can either arrange the tabs as you want and click the "Use Current Pages" button, or type them in manually, adding a `|` between tabs.

Answer (score 13):

Although you said it's best if it's not IE, I thought I'd mention (in case it helps someone else) that this is also possible in IE by going to:

```
Tools -> Internet Options -> General tab -> Home Page
```

And specifying each unique URL on a different line in the box, for example:

[image: IE Example]

Answer (score 10):

In **Opera**, this is possible as well.

If you open the pages you like, you can go into `Tabs and Windows > Sessions > Save This Session`, and click a checkbox to open these pages each time you start the browser.

Also, you can go into `Preferences: General: Startup`, and see options for:

- Resuming where you left off before closing the browser
- Resuming saved session(s)
- Showing a home page
- Showing Speed Dial

Answer (score 7):

For Firefox, there is an extension called "Morning Coffee" that I use for this:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/morning-coffee/?src=search

You can even set certain pages to open only on certain days. I have a "workday" set and a "weekend set".

Might be a little too rich for what you're trying to do, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

Simple Way in Chrome is include multiple URLs in the following screen (past in the URL):

```
chrome://chrome/settings/startup
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for Firefox's [App Tabs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/app-tabs-keep-favorite-websites-open):

> App Tabs allow you to always keep your favorite web apps like Facebook, Gmail and Twitter open and just a click away. App Tabs are small, can't be closed accidentally and open automatically when you start Firefox.

Just right-click any open tab, and click "Pin as App Tab".

Not only do they do everything you want, they also don't take up precious space in the tab-bar. Rather, they show up as small tabs with icons.

I'm surprised no one else suggested this.

Comment: Chrome introduced this with 'Pinned tabs', and you add them the same way as FF - right-click -> Pin tab.  I use these at work all the time.

Answer (score 3):

For Firefox there is an add-on called "[Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/)" that will save and restores the state of all windows - either when you want it or automatically at startup and even after crashes.
I've found this add-on very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you're using windows It's possible using a batch file (.bat) file.
Create a batch (.bat) file on desktop and paste the below code.

Note : Make sure you first open the browser then start the batch file so all the website will open in tabs, otherwise it would open in new browser window.

```
start www.google.co.in
start www.stackoverflow.com
start www.gmail.com
start www.twitter.com
start www.facebook.com
start www.plus.google.com
start www.superuser.com
```

Other method :

You can refer my article [how to setup multiple homepages in firefox browser.](http://devilsworkshop.org/how-to-set-multiple-homepage-in-mozilla-firefox/)

Answer (score 0):

You may have to download the latest version of Mozilla Firefox. Open all the pages you want, then you shuts down your computer and open Mozilla again, click on the transparent statement that asks you to restore to previous session at the bottom of your browser, and all the websites you previously opened will be opened for you.